# Как направить все ресурсы телефона на выполнение программы?

Tags: java, android

Я использую библиотеку opencv под андроид, вкратце программа находит нужный кадр из видео и определяет рост и параметры человека. На выполнение этой части кода(выполняется параллельно) уходит примерно 1.5 минуты на телефоне , есть ли какой-то способ , чтобы из приложения указать, что надо задействовать все ресурсы телефона? Или допустим использовать несколько процессоров?
P.S. хотя тот же код выполняли на java (Intelijie Idea) , он работал за 10 секунд.

Answer (score 1):

Ну прямо вот все ресурсы использовать не получится, но можно попробовать поиграть с приоритетами вашего процесса:

```
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(priority);
```

По умолчанию приоритет равен `0`, по идее можно повысить приоритет:

> **priority** - `int` a Linux priority level, from -20 for highest scheduling priority to 19 for lowest scheduling priority.

**Update**

Если речь идет об `AsyncTask`, то повысить приоритет можно так:

```
protected final MyResult doInBackground(MyInput... myInput) {
    Process.setThreadPriority(priority);
    // blah-blah
}
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35170962/472270)

Comment: А где правильнее добавлять этот кусок?Я использую AsynTask.

Comment: см. апдейт ответа